# Sending requests from Popup.html to Listener.js

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have the following:

**popup.html:**

```
        <!DOCTYPE html> 
    <html>
    <head>
    <style>
      body { width: 700px; }
      textarea { width: 250px; height: 100px;}
    </style>
    <script>
        function sendMessage(){
            chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
                chrome.tabs.sendRequest(tab.id, {method: "fromPopup", tabid: tab.id});});
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <button onclick="sendMessage(); ">Test</button>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**manifest.json:**

```
        {
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "ROBLOX Hub",
    "version": "1.1",
    "description": "A compilation of scripts to interact with the ROBLOX site.",
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "tabs",
        "<all_urls>"
     ],
    "content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
        "js": [ "jquery.min.js", "listener.js"],
        "run_at": "document_start",
        "all_frames": true
      }]
    }
```

**listener.js:**

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
if (request.method == "fromPopup") {
alert("I DID IT MOM")
});
```

However, when I hit "test" it doesn't seem to alert("I DID IT MOM"). Am I doing this correctly? I am guessing not as my script is not working. Basically it's supposed to send a message to the content script, "listener.js". Listener.js is running on all pages (as seen in manifest) and popup.html should be able to send the request to it, triggering the alert of "I DID IT MOM". What is wrong with my script? Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Bumping? Is that a thing on S.O.?

Comment: You should check your console logs (the one for popup.html is only available through the popup window).  They would have given you the error message that your original approach violates the content security policy.  They may also be giving you another error message that would help you debug what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since [CSP policy](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy), inline Js is not allowed in Chrome extension. Instead of doing that, you should reference your js code in html like `<script src="popup.js"></script>`, modify your button tag: `<button>Test</button>` and put code below into your `popup.js`.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', clickHandler);
  sendMessage();
});
```

Also keep in mind that [`chrome.tabs.sendRequest`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-sendRequest) and [`chrome.extension.onRequest`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension#event-onRequest) were deprecated and use [`chrome.runtime.sendMessage`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-sendMessage) and [`chrome.runtime.onMessage`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onMessage) instead.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this. I thought that sendMessage was being deprecated so that's why I used sendRequest instead, lol.

Comment: I'm running the scripts you told me to, but it still seems not to work. I added an alert in popup.js when it gets the message and changed the button like you told me to. I also removed the script for popup.html and instead put just "<script src="popup.js"></script>". Do I have to add anything to the manifest or something? Thanks.

Comment: Bumping with this comment... Sorry.

Comment: Could you open a new ticket to attach your code there? It seems clueless to figure out what's wrong without code.